# I get a Blank screen when using Windows IoT Remote Client

Tags: windows-10-iot-core

My Setup:

Windows 10 VM running in VirtualBox on Windows 7 Pro

Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core - 10.0.16299.19

The VM can see the RaspberryPi/Wionows IoT

I know this because:

- On the VMI I can Install and Debug from Visual Studio 2017 to the Pi.
- On the VM the IoT Dashboard detects the PI and allows me to change
  settings
- On the VM I can access the Pi's Device Portal
- On the VM I can use Powershell to log in to the Pi.

What I can't do is use Windows IoT Remote Client.  Which I want so I can see changes produced by my code.

When I start the client I get the spinning buffer animation followed by a blank, white screen.

I have tried the following as recommended in web articles:

- Reset the Pi resolution to 800x600 - This killed the Pi's ability to
  display at all; including on the attached HDMI.
- Checked Enable Windows IoT Remote Server in Device Portal. - This is
  set to On
- Disconnected the HDMI from the Pi - Made no difference.
- Typed the following into an Admin level PowerShell:

  net start WinRM

  Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 
  PiName

  This allowed Powershell access but no change to Remote Desktop

What should I try next?

Comment: It still not fixed in 10.0.17035.1000. I have NO idea how MS will promote this buggy software... Awful experience!

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: Same problem for v.10.0.17134.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On version 16299,the Windows IoT Remote client does not work for Raspberry Pi. Please reference the [know issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/commercial/fallcreatorsupdate#known-issues) of release notes for Windows 10 IoT 16299.Currently you can attach a monitor for local display.

Comment: Is there any hope that that feature and deployment from visual studios be reenabled/fixed?

Comment: Currently,there is no schedule for that.

Comment: I also have the same issue with Win IoT v.10.0.17134.1.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity, Windows IoT Remote client does not work for Raspberry Pi from 16299.

Comment: @michael-xu-msft, still not working on v.10.0.17763.107, does this means that Raspberry Pi is not one of the preferred platforms, and more things will stop to work going forward?

Comment: I have the same issue. Is IoT Core no more on focus on MS? The problem is noticed almost half a year ago.

Comment: I have the same issue, mouse works but there is still a white screen :(

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft.
"The Windows IoT Remote client does not work for Raspberry Pi. Use a board with accelerated graphics such as Minnowboard Max or Dragonboard or attach a monitor for local display."
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/remotedisplay

Answer (score -1):

Try starting the NanoRDP server manually (not through the web interface) and see if that helps.  That has solved a few issues for me.

I believe the executable is in `c:\windows\` and is called `nanordpserver.exe`.  just SSH or Powershell into the device, run `nanordpserver.exe` and try again.

The lightweight RDP protocol that IoT Core uses is not as robust as the version installed on the full Windows 10 OS.