# Remote Connection to "Raspberry Pi" via "Windows IoT Remote Client" leads to a white blank screen

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, remote-desktop, windows-10-iot-core

I have Windows 10 IoT installed on a Raspberry PI 3 B, and I am trying to connect to it via the [Windows IoT Remote Client](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/windows-iot-remote-client/9nblggh5mnxz) running on my laptop. ([+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/manage-your-device/remotedisplay))
As it mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/commercial/fallcreatorsupdate#known-issues) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935345/i-get-a-blank-screen-when-using-windows-iot-remote-client/46947766#46947766), there is a related known issue in Windows 10 IoT on build number 16299.
Consequently, when I try to connect my Raspberry PI via the Remote Client, it shows me only a white screen. However, it makes me able to use the mouse and keyboard connected to my laptop to control the Raspberry Pi.
In [the description of the known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/commercial/fallcreatorsupdate#known-issues), it says: "Drivers must be manually copied and registered on the device.".
**Then my question is** what do you know about the drivers that should be copied manually?
**And** is there any way except than waiting for next release of windows 10 IoT?

Comment: It is a known issue. From 16299, the Windows IoT Remote client does not work for Raspberry Pi. You can use a board with accelerated graphics such as Minnowboard Max or Dragonboard, or attach a monitor for local display with Raspberry Pi.  Sorry, i don't know if there is any plan about that.

Comment: @ParsaKarami, Yeah, I have currently connected an HDMI display to my hardware. But I wanna know if there is any way to make a remote connection.

Comment: i cannot find a way for remote on windows Iot with Raspberry Pi yet, if you want care your device and do not need interact with it, you can take screen shot and see the now situation.

Comment: @ParsaKarami, Thanks for your comments. Anyway, I think the only solution is waiting for the next release.